# Invalid form POST data. Error

Tags: ajax

I have a node form which I placed in a block, and user need to login to submit the form. There is a login link in the form itself where user can login which I implement through ajax and its working fine, but after login when the user submit the form it is not getting submitted and I am getting a "Invalid form POST data." error in "Recent log messages" in admin.

Anybody have any clue. I will post my code if needed.